# Can I use only Memgraph internal nodes IDs and relationships IDs?

Tags: memgraphdb

When I was learning about SQL databases we were always told to use unique ID. It could be auto generated or set by user. I see that every node and relationship in Memgraph has autogenerated ID. This are some internal IDs (I guess so).

Can I use only those Memgraph internal nodes IDs and relationships IDs or is it better to set my own node and relationship properties, e.g. myID, and then assign some value to it?